AWS deployment Options: ECS, Batch, Step Functions, which to use?
I am currently having a relatively huge batch logic analyzing transactions and purchase data, and applying dynamic pricing accordingly. It runs twice daily and takes around 2 hours to run. I am confused which AWS service I should use to deploy this logic.
I have considered and explored multiple options and got to the following:

lambda functions: a good and easy to set up option yet limited to 15 mins runtime --> hence excluded.
Step functions: I can divide my logic into multiple dependent steps, in my case each calling a lambda function doing part of the logic and building a workflow.
ECS with fargate: I can containerize my whole logic as a whole in one image on ECR and define a task on ECS and schedule it to run as desired, while fargate provisions the needed resources and manages the infrastructure and auto-scaling.
AWS Batch: managing my containerized logic with Batch jobs running it on the desired schedule.
I am confused whether to go to step functions, ECS, or Batch. Which should work better in my use case in terms of efficiency, pricing, ease of setup and complexity. And generally when to go to each or even mix some of them together. Would appreciate your help.

P.S: I have also tried automating the script through eventbridge rules by uploading it to S3 and triggering eventbridge rule at certain schedule to run it, yet I am having dependency issues with certain libraries am using so that's why I considered containerization.

I think ECS/Fargate is probably the solution here, with possibly Step Functions to orchestrate the ECS/Fargate tasks if your workflow is complicated enough. Or Step Functions + Lambda if each step can run in less than 15 minutes. It's really up to you, depending on what you are most comfortable working with. These AWS services are all building blocks that you can use to build your application, and there is not one "correct" answer to your question.

First, do you mean by a relatively huge batch logic? Is it like a C program that runs twice a day? Can you set it up on an EC2 instance; start the instance through EventBridge and run your program, and then stop the instance? That would be the easiest "lift and shift". Additional benefit that you can play with different sizes. Maybe 2xlarge will run in one hour, rather than two? You can also use Batch to set up the job that does all the steps.
If you can and want to split your a relatively huge batch logic thing into multiple modules - you may try to run them serverless; through lambda functions orchestrated by step functions - but from the question it is not clear what would be the purpose of such rewrite.
Finally, I am not clear why you are even considering containers. What do containers add that you can't have without them? Your question doesn't specify.

Well, good point yet with multiple scripts across team members and different instance specifications for each, dedicating an instance to run our scripts would not be efficient or even doable, we want to run it remotely to allow for different specifications and schedules as freely as possible .. but I have tried automating  scripts through eventbridge rules by uploading to S3 and triggering eventbridge rule at certain schedule to run it, yet I am having dependency issues with certain libraries in some scripts which is why I considered containerization.
